# PdfDocument layout

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, canvas

Hola quiero generar un PDF con la clase [`PdfDocument`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) de android del tamaño de una hoja carta. El layout que necesito debe tener un formulario e imagen. Con datos alineados en las esquinas como fecha, firmas, secciones en recuadros, pie de página, etc.

Buscando imágenes en internet encontré un layout que se asemeja a lo necesito, entonces, básicamente, ¿cómo genero el siguiente PDF?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿que tenes hasta ahora?

Comment: Pues hice un layout con medidas en reales (milímetros) pero no me gustó y terminé creando el pdf en el servidor y lo descargo al celular.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Con esto creas un docuemnto pdf de tamaño DIN A4

   PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();
   PageInfo pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595,842,paginas).create();

   Page pagina= document.startPage(pageInfo); //Esto crea la página a crear

   Canvas canvas=page.getCanvas();
    Paint paint=new Paint();
//x, y son los puntos donde quieres pintar el titulo y son puntos PostScript

  int x=50;

 int y=50;

    paint.setTextSize(18);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    canvas.drawText("TITULO",x,y,paint);

 //pintas más cosas

 document.finishPage(pagina);
```

Realmente es un trabajo laborioso porque tienes que hacer muchas pruebas de donde colocar cada cosa.